# How to convert layout in LESS to SCSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, less

I've got a layout coded in LESS and I need to implement it into a Rails application. As Rails straight use SCSS, I would like to use this instead of LESS.

Is there any tool that could do the conversion from LESS to SCSS for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any tools for converting except [this](http://nex-3.com/posts/100-convert-less-to-scss) which seems old & possibly not working.

However the syntax of less & scss is very similar, you could do a quick search and replace to convert variables like `@color: #4D926F;` to `$color: #4D926Fl;` & so on

It would require some time, but not as much as you might thing.

Comment: The only LESS -> Sass port that's difficult to do with a quick search/replace is mixin invocation because classes are mixins in LESS.

Comment: Also there might be some smarter ways to do things in Sass (or at least more things that you would approach differently), one thing that comes to my mind is dynamicly setting propery names (which is not possible in LESS and makes stuff much easier in Sass). You can also ignore this comment, if you don't care about such practices - or if it doesn't apply to anything in your speciffic case =) Good luck!